# What happens to the original commits when we use interactive rebase?

Tags: git, git-interactive-rebase

I am trying the interactive rebase. Assuming I have a linear master branch with 6 commits and the HEAD is on the 6th commit, and I run git rebase -i HEAD~4 then it allows me to pick/edit/split/squash the HEAD and the last 3 commits.

Once I do any of the action and complete the rebase operation, then it replays the commits on top of HEAD~4. Now, these have new commit ids and the head points to the most recent (picked) commit.

I want to know what exactly happens to the original commits? Are they deleted, are they retrievable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When a commit isn't referenced any more by a branch or a tag, it often still is in the [reflog](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog).

But when even the reflog clears up and the commit isn't referenced *at all*, then it becomes candidate for garbage collection, and ends up deleted, depending on your [gc config](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-gc#_configuration).

Comment: Important to note that this pretty much never happens immediately. In practice, the commits are quite available, and for a long time.